# Can base64 data URIs be used to point to an icon for a context menu item in Firefox extensions

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have a base64 string corresponding to a png icon image.
I'd like to add the corresponding icon image in a context menu item for a firefox extension as described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/menus/create

Unfortunately, there's no documentation explaining how to use data URIs for this purpose, so I don't even know if it's possible. I've tried the following code:

```js
        browser.contextMenus.create({
            id: id,
            title: title,
            contexts: contexts,
            icons: { 20: data:image/png;base64, base64string goes here!  }
        });
```

but with no success!

Comment: I don't have this set up to try out, but perhaps you need to simply enclose the string with quotes, for eg. `icons: { 20: 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mP8z/C/HgAGgwJ/lK3Q6wAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='}

Comment: Marvellous! I've posted it as an answer below, so you may accept that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON spec requires you to enclose the string with quotes, for eg.

```
...
`icons: {
    20: 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mP8z/C/HgAGgwJ/lK3Q6wAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='
}
...
```

I don't have the setup to try this out, but that should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Via aalaap:

You need to simply enclose the string with quotes, for eg. `icons: { 20: 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mP8z/C/HgAGgwJ/lK3Q6wAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='}